# Change incoming parameter for set expression

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services

I am creating a report that shows school grades from the previous year. Some subjects now have 2 teachers instead of 1 and we are looking to simply duplicate the grade the student has. The grade is found using the parameters:

@Initials    : the staff members initials

@SubjectName : name of the class taken

@StudentID   : student unique id number

So when @Initials comes through as ABC I need it to show the grade that student was given in that subject by XYZ. I have tried using an IIF function but cannot wrap my head around the logic of changing a Parameter within a set expression. Is there a way to use an IIF function on the parameter itself?

Thanks
Rob

Comment: There's not enough info to give a sensible answer and its not that clear what you are asking. Can you edit your question to show a sample of data from your dataset and/or database tables and the expected results based on that sample data. Include any relevant query statements too.

Comment: Its ok I sorted it, just hadn't had my coffee when I was looking at it. I just had to add CASE WHEN to the WHERE clause on the Dataset

Answer (score 0):

Just added CASE WHEN to the WHERE clause on the Dataset.

Remember for next time - have a coffee before attempting to think.